# Install tkinter for a different python version - arch linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, archlinux

My system main python version is `3.10.8`, although I neeed `3.9` version for some project, so I installed it using `sudo pacman -S python39`.
I require `tkinter` for a certain project, and the system already has it installed:

`pacman -Ss tk`:

```
extra/tk 8.6.13-1 [installed]
    A windowing toolkit for use with tcl
```

There is no issue if I attempt to import `tkinter` in the default python version:

```
python
Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov  1 2022, 14:18:21) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> quit()
```

However, I see the following problem when attempting to import `tkinter` with the different python version:

```
python39
Python 3.9.15 (main, Nov 17 2022, 21:04:43)
[GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>> quit()
```

As `tk` would not be "seeable" by python version 3.9.
I tried searching `tk` for other python versions, but `pacman` doesn't find any available package:

```
pacman -Ss python-tk
pacman -Ss python3-tk
pacman -Ss python39-tk
pacman -Ss python3.9-tk
pacman -Ss python-tkinter
pacman -Ss python3-tkinter
pacman -Ss python39-tkinter
pacman -Ss python3.9-tkinter
```

Comment: Consider looking into an environment manager such as Anaconda/Miniconda. It's not recommended to install multiple versions of Python alongside each other since they can lead to package conflicts such as this

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved by using `pyenv` to manage different python versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using `pyenv` to manage multiple python versions:

```
sudo pacman -S pyenv python-virtualenv
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

Then added these lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/home/andrea/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And finally:

```
pyenv install 3.9.15
pyenv virtualenv 3.9.15 my_virtual_environment
source ~/.pyenv/versions/my_virtual_environment/bin/activate.fish
python
Python 3.9.15 (main, Dec  5 2022, 15:02:48)
[GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> quit()
```

Comment: No need to install "python-virtualenv" instead you need to install "tk" package only